# Accessing array of objects assigned as a constant within an object and mapping its values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, object

/**If I need an array to map the values of genre as in the data below (drama/comedy/science) using map function,  how to access it. My code throws an error. Coding in React JS*/

I did achieve the results defining the data structure with array of objects directly in an object. But why is an array not accessed for map with this code.

```
const drama = [
    {name: "So {Long, My Son",
    rating: "5/5"},
    {name: "Schindlers List",
    rating: "4.5/5"},
  ]
 const comedy = [{
    name: "Snatch",
    rating: "4/5"},
    {name: "Two Barrels",
    rating: "4/5"}
  ];
  const science = [
    {name: "Interstellar",
    rating: "4/5"},
    {name: "ET",
    rating: "4/5"}
  ];
    const movies = {     /** Can I even define like this*/
    "Drama" : drama,
    "Comedy": comedy,
    "Science": science
    }; 



var [genreSelect, setgenreSelect] = useState("");
var movieList = Object.keys(movies);
  
  function clickHandler(x) {
    setgenreSelect(x);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>My Movie List</h1>
        <h3> Hit on the genres to check out my favourite movies</h3>
      </div>
      <nav class="navDiv">
        {movieList.map((genre)=>{
          return(
            <button class="btn" onClick={() => clickHandler(genre)}>{genre}</button>
          );        
        })}
      </nav>
      <ul class="list-nonbullet">

**/**-->> The part down  below throws an error. I have tried to access object[property] the value being an array defined */**

        {movies["genreSelect"].map((movie)=>(   
          <li class="listDiv">
            <div>{movie.name}</div>
            <div>{movie.rating}</div>
        </li> 
        ))}        
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _" Tell other readers what **the exact wording of the error message** is, and which line of code is producing it"_

Comment: `movies["genreSelect"].map(...)` - `movies` has no property `"genreSelect"`

Answer (score 0):

why are you using double quotes in this line {movies["genreSelect"].map((movie)=>(

it should be like this I guess {movies[genreSelect].map((movie)=>(

Comment: I did use without quotes. Most of whom I know  told me it would not work as the map function works only on an array. Bu I dont get why this is not returning an array.

Comment: const selectedMovies = movies[genreSelect];

try mapping selectedMovies.